# Query to Find out Deprecated Database Engine Features (SQL Server 2008 to 2014)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

Currently I am upgrading my SQL Server from 2008 to 2014, and I want to track the deprecated database engine features for one of my databases in the server.

I have read these articles in msdn:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190382.aspx

and found that this query can give me a brief picture of deprecated database engine features in my databases:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters   
WHERE object_name = 'SQLServer:Deprecated Features';
```

May I ask how I can figure out the instance name of my SQL Server? Can I specify an instance name so that the query only check for one of the database in my server?

Comment: the above query is working on instance level (all databases), not specific database, what is the issue of that ?

Comment: sorry that i am quite new to sql server, and first thanks for your answer. May i ask the meaning of instance level is the whole server but not one of the database in the server? My server contains lots of database from old version of sql server, so that there will be lots of deprecated features. Is it possible to just find out result of one of the database?

Comment: and also, May i ask how can i find out the instance name of the server in the sql management studio?

Comment: follow my below answer .

Answer (score 1):

The above query is working on instance level (all databases), not specific database.

and for getting the name of your instance, use one of the following queries:-

```
SELECT @@SERVICENAME
```

or

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('InstanceName')
```